# Chrome Developer Tools & Ember template file (.hbs)

Tags: ember.js, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Developer Tools, how can I view the Ember template file (.hbs)

It currently shows a tpl.js file (i.e. in place of tpl.hbs) ...i.e. somehow auto converts it into a JS file, but that JS has nothing from the template code?

Comment: You ll want to use the [ember inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en)

Comment: i did check that...could not find in the Ember inspector as well

Comment: Through the inspector you can find the template name, I don't think there are any tools to show you the hbs file as is since it gets compiled to js

Answer (score 0):

**The Short answer:**
You can't see hbs files on the client side in most ember rollouts.

**The Long Answer:**
You can't really see the template files in ember.js, especially since they are compiled on the server side and never sent to the client as hbs side

Furthermore I suspect you're trying to debug a template, for that there are some development helpers - http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/development-helpers/

You can either:

1. Use the Ember inspector, which will allow you to see the template names ,and then check the hbs on the server side to see what it looks like.
2. Use simple {{valueToTest}} like on the old printf on unix :)
3. Use debugger helpers to printout the current context on the template.

These are the ways that I use to debug template.